# Blog Title Tooltips are over-escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The new title tooltips for new blog posts are double-encoded.

In the page source, you can see

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(!window.localStorage || new Date(+localStorage.getItem('blog-new'))<new Date())document.write('<span title="SE Podcast #25 &amp;#8211; Mark Russinovich, by Alex Miller - 2 hours ago" class="new-blog-post">new<\/span>');</script>
```

The relevant part of this giant line is `document.write('<span title="SE Podcast #25 &amp;#8211; Mark Russinovich`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, it's actually quite a chore to setup locally, but the change looks good to fix double encoding.