# Why do career tooltips show html encoding characters for single quotes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, tooltips

See the image below where the tooltip shows `&#39;` instead a '

[image: Sample bug]

Comment: Related: [Blog Title Tooltips are over-escaped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110893/blog-title-tooltips-are-over-escaped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this should be better now. Let us know if you see it again.